# How can I add or delete the recipe in Yocto image by toaster

Tags: yocto, recipe

I use Yocto image to development some product.
And I need to add or delete recipe in my Yocto image.

I try to using toaster and success to analysis my Yocto image.
But I can't delete already including recipes.

This image is customized and already using in developing.

When starting the toaster, it doesn't have any UI for delete package or recipe.
Only can analysis build image.

Someone has any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

Open toaster and find the `bitbake variable` at bottom side. then you will find the `Add variable`.

1. To remove recipe use `IMAGE_INSTALL_remove`
2. To add recipe use `IMAGE_INSTALL_append`

Comment: I kwon this one. But depend and rdepend are making complicate to delete recipe. And I already analysis depend and it can be deleted recipe, but I want to more easy way.

Comment: I'm trying to remove iptables from my image using IMAGE_INSTALL_remove at the end of my custom image recipe, but it  doen't work.

Comment: you need to add in toaster gui